# Retrieving data from a dataframe by indexing using a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, pandas, indexing, tuples

I would like to know if there is a direct manner to pass a list of tuples (row_index, column_index) to a dataframe function in order to retrieve the data at these row and columns index? I indeed thought about using a list comprehension, but I want to know if there is no integrated thing for pandas?

Passing the ordered list of row_indexes and the ordered  list of column_indexes to loc merely retrieve the ensemble of intersections; so zipping is useless and the result irrelevant.

For instance, with

```
 df = pd.DataFrame ([[[0,1,2,3],[0,9,8,7]],[[0,1,8,3],[0,4,8,7]]],\
      index=["r0","r1"], columns =["c0","c1"])
```

if I have the list `l= [("r0","c0"),("r0","c1"),("r1","c1")]`
i can indeed use the list comprehension

```
[df[r,c] for r,c in l]
```

but I think I once so a possibility of passing such a list to df or arrays in a way that will retrieve the same result.
Was I mistaken?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: That is not valid dataframe construction code. Please fix it.

Comment: sorry, i forgot some brace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ([[0,1,2,3],[0,9,8,7]], index=["r0","r1"], columns =["c0","c1","c2","c3"])
l= [("r0","c0"),("r0","c1"),("r1","c1")]
print(df.lookup(*zip(*l)))
```

yields

```
[0 1 9]
```

Comment: Thank you @unutbu for the answer very helpful

Comment: Just to add, ```*zip``` actually unfolds the two row and column elements. ```zip(*l)``` produces ```[("r0", "r0", "r1"), ("c0", "c1", "c1")]```the two row and column elements. After that, ```*zip``` unfolds those elements by essentially doing ```df.lookup(zip(*l)[0], zip(*l)[1])```.

Answer (score 1):

Using `melt`

```
DF=df.reset_index().melt('index')
DF['Match']=list(zip(DF['index'], DF['variable']))
DF.value[DF.Match.isin(l)]

Out[249]: 
0    0
2    1
5    8
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

---

Data Input

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 9, 8, 7]], index = ["r0", "r1"])

l= [("r0",0),("r0",1),("r1",2)]
```